# Does the Block swap algorithm has any advantage over array reversal method, given that both have the same time complexity?

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm

Both these algorithm has a time complexity O(n) and space complexity is constant, the block swap seems more difficult. Is there any disadvantage of using it in CP or inteviews?

Comment: Reversing an array doesn't take O(n)

Comment: @karimfarhouti, it does take an O(n) time complexity just usually not space since you need a second container array to flip it.

Comment: @CayceK you only iterate through half the array and swap array[i] with array[n-i-1] ,and that makes it O(n/2)

Comment: @karimfarhouti unless I'm completely wrong you drop the `/2` because it is a constant and it is still considered O(n).

Comment: @CayceK if your're talking in general terms ,yes you're right it's the same linear complexity growth ,but since you mentionned competitive programming ,my mind shifted to the speed ,so my bad

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it probably belongs on [Computer Science](https://cs.stackexchange.com).

Answer (score 0):

Unless I'm mistaken reversal is just a form of block swapping. You could build your own reversal algorithm I guess, but that would likely be an insufficient use of time. In java there is the `Collections.reverse(class_obj)`. This is sufficient to use in an interview.

If you're tasked with doing another block swapping task then reverse is not what you're going to be using. You will have to likely come up with an iterative approach to successfully swap the array. Because of the nature of arrays in java you'll usually need an additional array to accomplish your task.